# Woocommerce / Mandrill setting up

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, mandrill, woocommerce-subscriptions

There will be dozens of stupid questions like "where should I put this code", sorry.

First of all, letting you know that I have almost zero knowledge about PHP (I know my problem could be solved via modifying default Wordpress php templates. I tried. I failed).

I have a website made on Wordpress. There's a Woocommerce store plugin. Now Woocommerce sends default emails (such as order confirmations, reset passwords, refunds, etc.). It works good.
At the same time I have all these transactional emails with a good design (not a default one, as you understand). And I want to integrate them with Mandrill (MailChimp SMTP).
These well-designed emails are from Figma + Emailify plugin for Figma. As I understood Mandrill's FAQ - all of my emails have necessary variables (I can see mc:repeatable, mc:editable variables in HTML).

Could someone explain me how do I force Mandrill to send my well-designed templates (such as reset password, order confirmation, etc.) instead of default ones? Please keep in mind that I have zero knowledge about coding.

Any ideas without coding? (I know there is email customizers for Woocommerce, but it doesn't fit my needs)

Expecting explanation on how to force Mandrill send my ready-made HTML templates.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. If you can't do that your post may be too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can upload ur readymade html template in mandril

and easily you can integrate template mentioning template_slug(unique_name) in ur code and start sending mail with from_email,to_email,subjec

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).